# bundler gem pessimistic semantic version string ~>1.7.15

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, semantics

I am noticing some unexpected behavior in ruby semantic version strings, for pessimistic operators.

I think `~> 1.7.15` should satisfy both `1.7.20` and `1.7.2`. But I tested with `Gem::Requirement.satifsfied_by?` and it says first one is `true` but the second one is `false`.

Same for `~> 0.9.26` and `0.9.30` and `0.9.3`.

Can someone explain why this is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding with regards to how [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) works.

If a library is at version `1.7.0`, and the author keeps bumping the **patch version number** in subsequent releases, then the library version increases as follows:

```
1.7.0
1.7.1
1.7.2
1.7.3
...
1.7.9
1.7.10
1.7.11
1.7.12
1.7.13
...
1.7.19
1.7.20
1.7.21
1.7.22
1.7.23
...
```

If at some point the **minor version number** is bumped, then the next release will be `1.8.0`.

Then later, if at some point the **major version number** is bumped, then the next release will be `2.0.0`.

---

Version `0.9.26` comes before `0.9.30`, but after `0.9.3`.

Version `0.9.30` and version `0.9.3` are *not the same thing*.

The version is a `String`, not a number.

Comment: amazing. got everything sorted out now.